# Session dies after page load in chrome nowhere else

Tags: php

Anyone have any suggestions or encountered this problem - since moving to an SSL chrome has just hated sessions. I've tried a very simple setting session and echoing it before it's set test - so after the second time the page loads the session displays. However EVERY browser works besides Chrome.

I've tried throwing this in but still doesn't work:

```
ini_set('session.use_trans_sid', false);
ini_set('session.use_cookies', true);
ini_set('session.use_only_cookies', true);
$https = false;
if(isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) and $_SERVER['HTTPS'] != 'off') 
{
  $https = true;
}
$dirname = rtrim(dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']), '/').'/';
session_name('token');
session_name('money_republic_token');
session_set_cookie_params(0, $dirname, $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'], $https, true);
session_start();
```

I am absolutely running out of ideas - why on earth would chrome treat sessions differently, even IE works!!

Answer (score 0):

If your site resides on localhost then probably you have hit this bug:

[chrome.cookies fails for localhost domains](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=56211):

Comment: it's on a server as said SSL